# variable is assigned to before nonlocal declaration

Tags: python-3.x, variables, syntax-error

Problem :

the variables offset_x, offset_y, in the block "event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION" give the error **SyntaxError: name 'offset_x' is assigned to before nonlocal declaration** I tried declaring those variable as global but I get the same error message. i dont know what to do.

```
import pygame as pg
import settings
from pointer import Pointer
import fractaltree
from railslider import Rail


pg.init()
# clock
clock = pg.time.Clock()


def screen_info_and_setfsrcreen():
    fullscreen_sz = pg.display.Info().current_w, pg.display.Info().current_h
    print('screen size =', fullscreen_sz)
    #if pg.display.Info().current_w != settings.width or pg.display.Info().current_h != settings.height:
    #    settings.screensize = (pg.display.Info().current_w - 100, pg.display.Info().current_h - 100)


screen_info_and_setfsrcreen()

screen = pg.display.set_mode(settings.screensize, pg.RESIZABLE)
# drawline for branches
global offset_x
global offset_y
offset_x = 0
offset_y = 0
def mousetraking(pointer):
    dragging = True
    if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

        if event.button == 1:
            if pointer.collidepoint(*pg.mouse.get_pos()):
                dragging = True
                (Xmouse, Ymouse) = pg.mouse.get_pos()
                offset_x = pointer.posx - Xmouse
                offset_y = pointer.posy - Ymouse
    elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        if event.button == 1:
            dragging = False

    elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
        if dragging:
            mouse_x, mouse_y = event.pos
            pointer.update(mouse_x + offset_x, mouse_y + offset_y)
            print("did something")

    if dragging == False or event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP or event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN or event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
        pointer.update(pointer.posx, pointer.posy)


# main loop
rail = Rail(20, 20, screen)
pointer = Pointer(20,20,screen)
dragging = False
displaying = True
while displaying:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            displaying = False
    mousetraking(pointer)
    rail.update()
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
    screen.fill(settings.white)

pg.quit()
```

Comment: Why don't you make your mouse tracking def statement return a tuple of x, y co-ords instead?

Comment: The exception suggests that you have a `nonlocal` statement somewhere, and in the text of your question you mention using `global`, but your code shows neither of those. Please show the code that's actually raising the error, or we can't help you debug it.

Comment: with this version of the code the error is UnboundLocalError: local variable 'offset_x' referenced before assignment, at the same line as before